# Different implementation of Eloquent instance for the same table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm currently working a tournament organization project, I would like to what's the best technique to have different implementation for the same model, for example I have model called `matches`, than retrieves data related to `matches`, but these `matches` may have different types depending on `match_type` field specified in `matches` model, what I did is creating parent class `/Match` , and having different types of matches extend this parent class. Ex:

```
Class SinglElimination/Match extends /Match{}
Class GroupStage/Match extends /Match{}
```

so with this design I have to get the parent match first to get the `match_type` then re-run the query to get a match with the needed child model

```
$match=Match::find($id);
$type = $match->match_type;
$childMatch = new $match_type.'/Match'();
$match = $match->where('_id', $this->_id)->first();
```

which I know is nowhere near clean, so how would you implement this ?

Comment: `new $match_type.'/Match'();` is this a valid PHP syntax?

Comment: not sure but i have an implementation that looks like it, i just wrote it that way to show the idea not the syntax

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would separate those 3 classes and exclude any extending. Take a look at `Polymorphic` relationships in `Laravel`, here is the [quick link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations). It will be a `cleaner` approach and in my opinion it would be the best approach here, all you'll have to do is design the `tables` properly and do `relationships` properly too.

Comment: but what if the match is a stand_alone model, which doesn't have relation with another class, how would i use polymorphics relations there ?

Comment: Well `polymorphic` relationship demands you have a relationship between multiple models, in case where `Match` doesn't have a relationship with any class, then you will need to use `DB` facade to create a handmade query to fetch the target entity instead of catching `Match` class and then what you need.